# How to stop a program that is not showing up using monit?

Tags: process, browser, monit

I have a set of raspberry running raspbian.

On each of these, I have configured monit to monitor the epiphany browser, which should always show up with a specific web site.

Unfortunatly, some times (like now), any of the raspberry will boot without the epiphany window visible ... which is strange, considering that

1 - the epiphany process exists :

```
ps aux | grep epiphany
pi        2564 10.7 12.7 384764 121168 ?       Sl   06:22   1:00 epiphany-browser http://163.83.104.41:9000/skillCenter/SGE/slideshow
pi        2842  0.0  0.1   3568  1828 pts/0    S+   06:32   0:00 grep --color=auto epiphany
```

2 - monit can see this process and consider it alive

[image: Monit considers the epiphany process as running]

Notice monit observes the epiphany process using this config

```
check process epiphany  matching "epiphany"
    if cpu > 95% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 99% for 5 cycles then exec /sbin/reboot
    # reboot if process is dead
    if changed pid then exec /sbin/reboot
    # or if process never started
    if does not exist for 10 cycles
            then exec /sbin/reboot
```

3 - the question

So ... how can I tell monit this process is not visible on my Gnome desktop to have configured monitoring actions triggered ?